# Cannot reach more than 60 FPS

Tags: performance, ubuntu, warsow

Yesterday I installed this game on my PC on Ubuntu 13.04 OS (since for some crazy reason I can't start game on Windows 8) and then I tried to increase FPS at 125 by using: `cl_maxfps 125`. But the thing is that it blocks at 60 FPS. And I know that my PC can run this game at more then 60 FPS.

Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: I bet your screen is set to 60Hz **and** you have Vsync on.

Comment: PS: When I said *Vsync*, I meant *double-buffered Vsync*.

Comment: The fact that his screen is running 60hs doesn't mean he can't run more than 60 fps. I play **Quake Live** with 125fps, using a 60hz monitor, and it happened me before: it was the `V-Sync` option.

Comment: @Fabián V-sync is directly related to the monitor's refresh rate, so a screen running 60Hz *does* matter.

Comment: Of course it matters. The only thing I meant is that the monitor can't prevent you from running more than 60 fps.

Comment: @Fabian: No, but it does prevent you from getting any benefit from any FPS higher than 60...

Comment: Maybe this is a goofy question, but why do you need to run at >60FPS? 60FPS is already twice as fast as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deactivate `V-Sync`. That happens in any game with **Vertical Sync** activated.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. I will try that. Just to google a bit how to deactivate it on Linux. :)

Comment: See this: http://www.warsow.net/forum/thread/t/203155