# How do I maximize FPS?

Tags: league-of-legends

I run league of legends on the highest graphics settings. Even when I play the game on low I still sit at 60 FPS. My resolution is 1920x1080.

- My PC specs are a i3 3rd gen 3.3GHz Prossecor
- NVIDIA GTX650 Ti Boost GPU

How can I increase my fps? I understand the eye can't see more then 60FPS but in teamfights when there is a lot of parcticle effects(Lux using Final Spark) I can drop to 15 which makes the game choppy. I do have Vertical Sync on.

Comment: I don't play LoL, but what would V-Sync effect if it was turned off? That seems to be a major frame killer in most games. Also, is there a way to turn down particle effects? If so, try doing both of those.

Comment: I'm not sure. As I don't really understand the full effect of it. I know it keeps the frames of the game together so prevents screen tear.

Comment: @ShadowZ Vertical sync isn't a frame killer per se, it makes sure the frame sent to the monitor does get there while the monitor refresh. If it is turned off, it will send the frame regardless. It can help get a tad higher recorded fps but if its fps drop to 15, vertical sync off won't help much.

Comment: Could it just be the i3 processor lagging behind in high impact team fights with lots of particle effect happening?

Comment: Turn your settings off of the highest

Comment: But it doesn't increase my fps? Or you talking about it in the aspect that if i turn down the settings then I don't lose frames?

Comment: Try using an application of the like of [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) and also, if possible with a second monitor, check your cpu usage. I would bet LoL might be getting more multi-threaded and your cpu is holding back your card. There's quite a few google results saying your card should run LoL quite fine with good settings. Try lowering your resolution a notch.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Is MSI Afteburner only for MSI GPU's? I can easily monitor my usage. I should of added I have 8GB of Ram and my GPU has 2GB

Comment: No, it will work with all NVidia gpu. It worked well with my Palit gtx 460 and I'm sure it will work with my gtx 980 if I try it when at home tonight. With it, you'll be able to pinpoint where the bottleneck is : Cpu or Gpu.

Comment: V-Sync limits your fps to 60. Deactivate it and you're good to go. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129559/warsow-cannot-reach-more-then-60-fps

Comment: @Fabiàn Wrong, V-sync limits the fps to the refresh rate of the monitor used, v-sync will not limit to 60 a 120hz monitor.

Comment: Well, V-Sync **limits** your fps, that's the most important part. He wants to get the maximum FPS possible.

Comment: He stated that the monitor resolution is 1920x1080, the bigger it is, the more V-Sync processing will need (ofc is the same with everything else in video quality). And there isn't much difference with V-Sync in terms of good-looking unless you get used to it **BUT if you care about gameplay** then it is strongly recommended to visualize how much FPS you have above the 120 just to be sure you can cover any amount of special effects in any situation. That's why **V-Sync is often deactivated**.

Comment: @Fabián V-sync doesn't use any processing power, either gpu or cpu... please, read what [V-sync](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=358751) [is before](http://www.tweakguides.com/Graphics_9.html) saying anything else about vertical synchronization

Comment: You should not be having a low frame rate with those specs, to be honest.  I don't even drop down that low with my laptop, and it doesn't have dedicated graphics

Comment: Thanks for the info @Jonathan, I was wrong and it doesn't affect performance. However, if your frame rate goes above and below 60 fps (or matching the refresh rate of your monitor), v-sync still isn't a good idea, since automatically halves your fps cap for the purposes of no-tearing (and can become an annoying experience). Unless your fps goes always higher than the actual monitor's refresh rate, you shouldn't activate it.

Comment: In the end V-Sync was the problem my FPS spiked to a high 130 FPS on avg after.

Comment: @Charkz That should not cause your FPS to drop to 15 though or solve that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60 FPS is far faster then the eye can tell the difference, top motion animations (even today ) is only up to 40 or so fps May I suggest removing you shaders and if you do want higher fps to remove v-sync!

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: Where do you get that idea from that 60 FPS is faster than what the eye can see? This is just wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Shaders are the bane of every graphics card's existence. Turn down the shaders and anti-alising and you should see an improvement.

The 60 FPS is because it's locked to your screen's refresh when V-Sync is turned on. While it can prevent tearing, usually you can safely leave this turned off (I do and don't notice anything different). My money's on the anti-aliasing/shader settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn all graphics down to the lowest.
2. Set resolution to the lowest (800x600 I believe) - note this will not lower your field of view, just the resolution.
3. Keep the game on fullscreen
4. Turn OFF vsync
5. Get rid of nonessential apps in the background

Your specs should give you pretty consistent 40+ FPS. If you do 1-4 and make sure 5 is done right you should be fine.